# File upload doesn’t work on Android (no apps can perform this action)

Tags: android, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using WordPress and Contact Form 7 plugin on [this](https://magazeta.com/jobs/add-cv/) page. There is a file upload field, it's simple and valid HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="your-cv" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

The form works perfectly on desktop, iOS, but Android users can’t use file upload. They just cannot choose a file with “file chooser” on android. After they click on “file picker”, android dialogue window with “no apps can perform this action” text will appear.

[android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqUYE.jpg)

How can I solve this?  Users reported, that they don't have such problem on other websites.

Thanks.

Comment: Just tried on my android, and I had no problems selecting a file

Comment: I added an application from my android, with the name test tester or something like that

Comment: note for further investigation - I used a one+ 3 android device,running OxygenOS, with android version 8, also maybe related, I have development mode on

Comment: As I know most Android devices don't have default app for viewing/select files, especially PDFs, docs (I have access parameter in my input-tag). So that's why most users can't select the file to upload. But how other websites solve this problem?

Comment: when I clicked it, I could see all of my files, JPGs, GIFs, PDFs, etc. and select them all - I did it through Chrome.